# Distinguish two comparable teams

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms, word-choice

Let's imagine I have two teams in my club. Both are equally skilled and I want both to have a name that reflects that, so no Team 1 and Team 2 because Team 2 sounds worse than Team 1. Alpha and Bravo are also not possible because Bravo is a step down from Alpha. What could be a good name for my two teams so they don't feel one is preferred or has the advantage over the other team?

Comment: A2 and B1? ....

Comment: Team Osmium and Team Iridium. The Bears and the Cougars.  Isis and Goldie.

Comment: Red Team, Blue Team, and for a third; Orange Team etc...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- Cougars, Mountain Lions, Pumas, Panthers
- Tigers and Lions
- Hawks and Eagles
- Spartans and Trojans
- Pulverizers and Crushers
- East and West
- Stars and Astros
- Invincibles and Champions
- Rockers and Rollers
- Mustangs and Stallions
- Surf and Waves
- Quasars and Pulsars
- Photons and Quarks
- Marauders and Pillagers

Comment: niceee..However, no match for something truly invincible.

Answer (score 4):

One, sir, looks for such equivical names in ancient mythologies.Thus, how about the name **Ares**, the Greek god of war, and his Roman equivalent **Mars**.

Comment: Excellent idea. I really like the idea of fitting the purpose and adding a little cultural education at the same time!

Comment: East and West and Ares and Mars are both really good haha.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you call them **Team A** and **Team 1.**

Comment: This would cause confusing I think...

Answer (score 1):

Possibly X and Y have less of an implied preference?

I once made the mistake of using Red and Green for this kind of thing, some people saw Green as positive and Red negative.

One possibility let the teams choose their own names from some domain: Bach and Mozart anyone?

I would probably choose two very positive nouns such as Lions and Tigers.

Answer (score 0):

I think two words that are synonyms would work.
Like for instance: a cougar is a mountain lion. 
Or **Sprite** and **7-Up** —same thing different name.
**Mercury** and **Hermes** same person different culture titles. 
You could even be clever and use different languages. **Team 
Uno** and **Team Une**.

You could also let the two teams come up with their own names. 
 That said make them reveal at the same time so one team doesn't try to trump the other.